# Aura: can I add a help text to an accordion section?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, helptext, accordion

I have the following code:

```
<lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion1" allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true">
    <lightning:accordionSection name="Selected" label="Selected">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <c:strokeSelector aura:id="selectedStyle" properties="{!v.stroke}"/>
        </div>
    </lightning:accordionSection>
```

This appears as:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to add a help text to the accordion, so that I can explain what "Selected" means.

Is that possible? I added `<lightning:helptext` but it appeared below not next to the Accordion title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use action attribute which can have component as its value but you have to change the css manually to put it at correct place

```
<lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion" activeSectionName="B">
        <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="Accordion Title A" >
            <aura:set attribute="actions">
                  <lightning:helptext
        content="The tooltip displays on the lower left of the icon or above the icon if space is available. It automatically adjusts its position according to the viewport."
    />
            </aura:set>
            <aura:set attribute="body">
                <p>This is the content area for section A.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>The section height expands to fit your content.</p>
            </aura:set>
        </lightning:accordionSection>
     
    </lightning:accordion>
```

and in css

```
.THIS .slds-form-element__icon{
    left: 187px;
    position: absolute;
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this with the built-in component. You could write your own custom component, though.